# Display not rotated with framebuffer console

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, framebuffer, display-rotation

I have enabled rivers->Graphics Support->Support for framebuffer devices->Framebuffer Console Support by '*'(builtin driver) in my kernel and compiled it. My aim is to rotate the display by writing different values to the file **/sys/class/graphics/fbcon/rotate** as suggested by this link : https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/fbcon.txt.
I am trying to rotate the display with below commands from commandline...

```
root@sanjeev:~# cat /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/rotate
0
root@sanjeev:~# echo 1 >> /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/rotate
root@sanjeev:~# cat /sys/class/graphics/fbcon/rotate
0
root@sanjeev:~#
```

The display is not rotated, and the value is not written on this file.

Then I tried writing values to **/sys/class/graphics/fb0/rotate** as below...

```
root@sanjeev:~# cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/rotate 
0
root@sanjeev:~# echo 1 >> /sys/class/graphics/fb0/rotate 
root@sanjeev:~# cat /sys/class/graphics/fb0/rotate 
1
root@sanjeev:~#
```

This time the screen blinked, but not rotated. Also the value is written to this file as can be seen from the above log.

Is it possible to rotate the display in this way?? I am using ubuntu version 15.10 and my laptop has two graphics cards(nVidia 3D controller, and Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller).

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable support for frame buffer rotation,

-> Device Drivers                                                                                                                   │
│       -> Graphics support                                                                                                               │
│         -> Console display driver support

To be enabled:
[]Framebuffer Console Rotation //press y to enable

This worked for me